# Commutative artinian ring is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, alternative-proof, noetherian

Suppose R is a commutative Artinian ring then R is Noetherian.

I am aware of the proof which uses the idea of filtration. But I would like to prove this fact without that idea but haven't got far enough. Is there any reference for such a proof? or is anyone aware of one?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a direct proof that the Jacobson radical $J$ of an Artinian ring is nilpotent.

We know that $J^n = J^{n+1}$ for some $n \geq 1$. Let $X = \{a \in A : aJ^n = 0\}$; it is enough to show $X = A$ as then $1 \in X$ and $J^n = 0$.

Now if $X < A$ then we can find a minimal non-zero submodule $Y/X$ of $A/X$ because $A$ is Artinian. Then $Y/X$ is a simple $A$-module, so the definition of the Jacobson radical as the simultaneous annihilator of all simple modules implies that $YJ \subseteq X$. Hence

$$YJ^n = YJ^{n+1} = YJ.J^n \subseteq XJ^n = 0$$

and hence $Y \subseteq X$. This contradicts the assumption that $Y/X$ is non-zero. Thus $X = A$ as required.

This proof also works in the non-commutative case, and shows that a right Artinian ring is right Noetherian.

Comment: When you write $X<A$, does that mean that $X$ has less elements than $A$ (and hence that it's smaller) or that $X$ is a subset of $A$?

Comment: Why does it show that Artinian ring is Noetherian? Is it true that if Jacobson radical is nilpotent then a ring is Noetherian?

Comment: $X < A$ means that $X$ is a proper subset of $A$.

If $J^n = 0$, then the ring is a finite extension of the modules $J^i / J^{i+1}$ for $i=0,...,n-1$. Each of these modules is on the one hand Artinian, being a subquotient of the Artinian ring $R$, and on the other hand, semisimple, being a module over the semisimple Artinian ring $R/J$. But semisimple Artinian modules are Noetherian. So, the ring $R$ itself must be Noetherian.

Comment: If $R = A / J^2$ where $A$ is a polynomial ring over a field in infinitely many variables $x_i$ and $J$ is the ideal generated by all the $x_i$, then the Jacobson radical $J/J^2$ of $R$ is nilpotent, but $R$ is not Noetherian. 

In this example, $R$ is not Artinian. So, there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

This is a vague but subtle question.  [Here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~lempp/conf/asl12/Slides/Conidis.pdf) are some slides of Chris Conidis that take it very seriously.

To paraphrase, the question is this: All standard proofs that Artinian implies Noetherian prove the stronger statement that Artinian implies finite length.  Is there a proof that manages to be simpler by failing to prove the latter?

Conidis gives an affirmative answer, for countable rings, by giving a proof which is valid in an axiomatic system too weak to prove finite length.

I don't have time to finish this line of exploration myself, but I thought it might be of interest (and it also pinpoints nilpotence of the Jacobson radical as the sticking point).  There seem to be at least a few papers out there talking about this.

Comment: In the presence of Artinian, finite length is equivalent to Noetherian. So not stronger, strictly speaking.

Comment: @KonstantinArdakov First of all, it's prima facie true that finite length is stronger than the descending and ascending chain conditions put together.  Second of all, there are axiomatic systems, specifically [WKL0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Weak_K.C3.B6nig.27s_lemma_WKL0), in which Artinian implies Noetherian but in which there exist commutative Artinian rings of infinite length.

Comment: @KonstantinArdakov But all of this is just means to an end: it is often hard to tell what is meant by "a _different_ proof" or "a proof not using idea X".  This is just an attempt to make the question more explicit: The proof of Conidis is obviously not equivalent from the standard one, because it is valid even when the standard one isn't.

Comment: I always assume the axiom of choice holds. This makes my life easier.

Answer (score 3):

"Steps in Commutative Algebra" by "R. Y. Sharp"
8.39 LEMMA. Let R be a commutative Artinian ring. Then every prime
ideal of R is maximal.
8.40 LEMMA. Let R be a commutative Artinian ring. Then R has only
finitely many maximal ideals.
8.41 PROPOSITION. Let R be a commutative Artinian ring, and let N =
$\sqrt 0$, the nilradical of R. There exists  t such that N^t = 0.
7.30 THEOREM. Let G be a module over the commutative ring R, and
assume that G is annihilated by the product of finitely many (not necessarily
distinct) maximal ideals of R, that is, there exist maximal ideals
M_i,..., M_n of R such that M_i... M_n G = 0. Then G is a Noetherian R-module if and only ifG is an Artinian R-module.

SO:
8.44 THEOREM. A commutative Artinian ring R is Noetherian.

Comment: What is the method of proof for 7.30?  I believe this is where the "filtration idea" is used.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I think this traverses the same filtration, just inductively, but I find it more clear.